# jOOQ - How to update a jsonb column with an array in a Postgres table to avoid SQLDialectNotSupportedException

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jooq

I have a PostgreSQL table with a jsonb column which contains an array of strings that are tag values, like so:`["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]`. I have a custom binding that converts JSON to and from jackson JsonNode.

The custom binding is defined here: https://gist.github.com/HelgeG/0c0b14228f75e91b7542bd6979a05b49

The record is read with a basic find and then I extract the JSON column as follows:

```
VRelease release = releaseModel.find(id);
JsonNode tagNode = release.getTags();
```

The node is converted to a `List<String>`

```
  List<String> tagList = objectMapper.readValue(
      tagNode.toString(),
      objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(
          List.class, String.class));
```

I then add a string to the list and convert the list back to a JSON formatted string

```
  tagList.add(tag);
  String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(tagList);
```

Then I convert the JSON formatted string into a JsonNode, and try to write it back to the database:

```
  releaseModel.writeTags(id, objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonNode.class));
```

The `writeTags` method simply does the following:

```
  public int writeTags(Integer id, JsonNode tagList) {
    return ctx.update(TABLE).set(field(TAG_FIELD_NAME), tagList).where(PRIMARY_KEY.eq(id))
        .execute();
  }
```

However, on executing this query, I am getting the following exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode is not supported in dialect POSTGRES
```

Inspecting the JsonNode object in the debugger, it has the value:

[image: JsonNode in debugger]

I have been struggling with this for quite some time now, and would appreciate any pointers from jOOQers with more experience than me on how I can successfully write the JSON array to the database.

This is with jOOQ v3.9.5 and PostgreSQL 9.6.5.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. What I meant to ask is how you set that `List<String>` to the field. I mean you're passing that `List<String>` to the `set()` method, but how did you specify `TAG_FIELD_NAME`'s `DataType`? Is it a `DataType<List<String>>`? How did you configure the binding? The binding you've linked is a `Binding<Object, JsonNode>`, but from your posted code, there should be a `Binding<Object, List<String>>` instead...

Comment: @LukasEder I see where the confusion comes from as I am reusing the same variable name in different contexts (once for the list, the other time for the JsonNode) without properly describing it. By the time I call the writeTags method I am passing a JsonNode object, not a List.  Above I have included a screenshot of the value of the JsonNode in the debugger. Apologies for being unclear, and thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `TAG_FIELD_NAME` is just a simple `String` that describes your column name. In that case, the explanation is very simple. jOOQ doesn't know anything about your custom `Binding` for the `JsonNode` type, let alone for a `List<ArrayNode>`.

Your code compiles because you're using [`DSL.field(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-) which returns a `Field<Object>`. But such a field can only be used with an "ordinary" JDBC type that both jOOQ and the JDBC driver know what to do with. In order to actually *bind* the data type binding to your field, you have to provide it to jOOQ. Write this instead:

```java
DataType<List<ArrayNode>> ARRAY_NODE_LIST = SQLDataType.OTHER.asConvertedDataType(
    new ArrayNodeListBinding());
```

Then use it as follows:

```java
ctx.update(TABLE)
   .set(field(TAG_FIELD_NAME, ARRAY_NODE_LIST), tagList)
   // your new data type here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   .where(PRIMARY_KEY.eq(id))
   .execute();
```

Now you only have to write that binding. The binding you posted doesn't work here, because it binds `JsonNode`, not `List<ArrayNode>`

Comment: As a general form of handling JSON strings with variable contents, could I then use a binding that translates between a regular String and the PostgreSQL JSONB column type and use it the same way as outlined above?

Comment: Sure, it would be less specific than the above, and only accept the common super type for variable JSON content (instead of a `List<ArrayNode>`), but that is probably more suitable for most cases...